# Unable to Upload image to php server iOS (error PHP Notice: Undefined index: filename )

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, file, upload

In my ios application,I am trying to upload an image using the code below.According to my API documentation it is mentioned **"input : file as multipart form data with ‘filename’ as object name"**.Now when i run this code,I am getting the following error in the error log(in the terminal).

```
"{"FileUpload1":{"name":"image.jpg","type":"image\\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\\/tmp\\/phpwUhnu3","error":0,"size":347593}}
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: filename in /var/www/html/utilities/helpers.php on line 307"
```

my code:

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",TEST_BASE_URL,FILE_UPLOAD_URL];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];


    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [urlRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // Add __VIEWSTATE
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"__VIEWSTATE\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"/wEPDwUKLTQwMjY2MDA0M2RkXtxyHItfb0ALigfUBOEHb/mYssynfUoTDJNZt/K8pDs=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add image data
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"FileUpload1\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTa..........etc
```

I don't have experience using multi part form data.In the above code,filename parameter is not appearing in the terminal output.Or if you know how to do,please help me.Thanks.

Comment: seems like error is in php side

Comment: Did you mean that the multi part form data is not formatting the input correctly in the server side?

Comment: because it's hard to say what's wrong, please try the call first with a rest client  i.e. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com)  this way you know if it is server related or not